# Reinitialize log4j on web app deployment using Log4jConfigListener

Tags: java, jboss, log4j

I have setup Log4jConfigListener in my web.xml and it works fine, however, if I redeploy the web app without restarting the server then log4j shuts down and does not reinitialize.  If I remove the Log4jConfigListener from my web.xml then everything works fine.

I am using JBoss 4.2.3-GA as the app server.  I notice that when I am not using the config listener then I do not see any output that Log4J was shutdown, so perhaps the issue is that the web app is shutting down JBoss's log4j LogManager.

Is there a way to configure it properly, or should I avoid using Log4jConfigListener in development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Log4jConfigListener` doesn't really play nice in situations where the app server manages log4j itself (as it does in this case). The two are going to end up getting into a tug-of-war over who gets to configure log4j.

I suggest not using `Log4jConfigListener` with JBoss, and rely instead on JBoss's own log4j configuration.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing.  I couldn't see much reason to use the log4jconfiglistener.  Thanks.